# Does this Camera Lens to Mobile phone camera interface exist?

Tags: canon, lens-adapter, cameraphones

I've seen this ad come up on a web site.
(I've cropped the image)

[image]

It looks like a canon lens has an interface to a camera phone.  I believe that this is a gimmick but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know if this is real?

Comment: [Google sayth](https://www.google.com/search?q=canon+lens+mobile+phone+adapter) - [Adapter Puts Nikon and Canon Lenses on Iphone](http://www.wired.com/2011/07/adapter-puts-nikon-and-canon-lenses-on-iphone/)

Comment: Please buy one and report back how well a 24-70mm f/2.8 performs on your iPhone :)

Comment: It seems to be real but it also seems to be a way to get the bulk of an entry-level DSLR or CSC camera while losing any auto-focus, metering or VR features of your old DSLR lenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Photojojo lens mount, and you can find the product [on this link](http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/iphone-slr-mount/).

Comment: the link go's to a "no longer available" page

Comment: The PhotoJojo SLR mount is no longer available for purchase.

Answer (score -2):

mCam pro iPhones 6-7

I have been doing a little bit of research on them they seem to be one of the better camera adapter’s around there are linens adapters for Canon and Nikon